# Angular2 - Pagination error

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ng2-bootstrap

I installed ng2-bootstrap as pagination component. I found the help from (https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/pagination#pager-component) setting up the component easily.

Pagination also works fine as expected.

But I am facing problem with running the existing test case. While I try to run older test cases, I am getting so many test cases because of the newly included pagination code in the **component.html" .

```
<pagination [totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow" class="pagination-sm"
    [boundaryLinks]="true" [rotate]="false" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [itemsPerPage]="numberOfItemsPerPage" (numPages)="totalNumberOfPages = $event"></pagination>
```

These are the few errors that I am getting while I tried to run the test cases.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'totalItems' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"  class="pageButton">
            <pagination [ERROR ->][totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow""): SearchResultComponent@84:24
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("ol-md-6 col-lg-6"  class="pageButton">
            <pagination [totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow" class="pagination-sm"
            "): SearchResultComponent@84:60
Can't bind to 'maxSize' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("tton">
            <pagination [totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [ERROR ->][maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow" class="pagination-sm"
                    [boundaryLinks]="true" ["): SearchResultComponent@84:92
Can't bind to 'boundaryLinks' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. (")]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow" class="pagination-sm"
                    [ERROR ->][boundaryLinks]="true" [rotate]="false" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [itemsPerPage]="numberOfI"): SearchResultComponent@85:20
Can't bind to 'rotate' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("[maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow" class="pagination-sm"
                    [boundaryLinks]="true" [ERROR ->][rotate]="false" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [itemsPerPage]="numberOfItemsPerPage" (numPages)"): SearchResultComponent@85:43
Can't bind to 'itemsPerPage' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("m"
                    [boundaryLinks]="true" [rotate]="false" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [ERROR ->][itemsPerPage]="numberOfItemsPerPage" (numPages)="totalNumberOfPages = $event"></pagination>
       "): SearchResultComponent@85:96
'pagination' is not a known element:
1. If 'pagination' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pagination' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"  class="pageButton">
            [ERROR ->]<pagination [totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfBu"): SearchResultComponent@84:12
No provider for NgControl ("></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"  class="pageButton">
            [ERROR ->]<pagination [totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfBu"): SearchResultComponent@84:12
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'totalItems' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("     <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"  class="pageButton">
            <pagination [ERROR ->][totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow""): SearchResultComponent@84:24
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("ol-md-6 col-lg-6"  class="pageButton">
            <pagination [totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [ERROR ->][(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow" class="pagination-sm"
            "): SearchResultComponent@84:60
Can't bind to 'maxSize' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("tton">
            <pagination [totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [ERROR ->][maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow" class="pagination-sm"
                    [boundaryLinks]="true" ["): SearchResultComponent@84:92
Can't bind to 'boundaryLinks' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. (")]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow" class="pagination-sm"
                    [ERROR ->][boundaryLinks]="true" [rotate]="false" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [itemsPerPage]="numberOfI"): SearchResultComponent@85:20
Can't bind to 'rotate' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("[maxSize]="numberOfButtonsToShow" class="pagination-sm"
                    [boundaryLinks]="true" [ERROR ->][rotate]="false" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [itemsPerPage]="numberOfItemsPerPage" (numPages)"): SearchResultComponent@85:43
Can't bind to 'itemsPerPage' since it isn't a known property of 'pagination'. ("m"
                    [boundaryLinks]="true" [rotate]="false" (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)" [ERROR ->][itemsPerPage]="numberOfItemsPerPage" (numPages)="totalNumberOfPages = $event"></pagination>
       "): SearchResultComponent@85:96
'pagination' is not a known element:
1. If 'pagination' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'pagination' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"  class="pageButton">
            [ERROR ->]<pagination [totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfBu"): SearchResultComponent@84:12
No provider for NgControl ("></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"  class="pageButton">
            [ERROR ->]<pagination [totalItems]="totalNumberOfRecords" [(ngModel)]="currentPageNumber" [maxSize]="numberOfBu"): SearchResultComponent@84:12
    at SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:2043:33)
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:64958:16)
    at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:5443:16)
    at TemplateParser.parse (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:17883:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:48480:68)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:48363:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:48363:19)
    at createResult (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:48265:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.470.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1415:26)
    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:79182:39)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:79874:39)
    at ZoneDelegate.470.ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1414:32)
    at Zone.470.Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1211:43)
    at http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1764:57
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1728:31) [ProxyZone]
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1704:17) [ProxyZone]
    at http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1764:17 [ProxyZone]
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?064cb70427ca5b910f9a6b38441f4814b1f3c15d:79901:39) [ProxyZone]
    at ZoneDelegate.470.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1447:36) [ProxyZone]
    at Zone.470.Zone.runTask (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1251:47) [<root> => ProxyZone]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1614:35) [<root>]
    at ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:1505:25) [<root>]
    at data.args.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0a9ca230b4630dbd5dca0d237827921c6470f2c7:2612:25) [<root>]
```

For simplicity I have not include the other error coming from the **pagination** html tag. It causes error from all its **attributes** inside the **pagination** tag.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you add the pagination module to module imports? Please add the test code to your question.

Comment: No I don't added any extra code for testing pagination. But I have added the **import { PaginationModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/pagination';** and also added **PaginationModule.forRoot()** in the **@NgModule**.

Comment: You have to add all stuff such `FormsModule` and `PaginationModule` in your testing module otherwise you have to use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` to prevent getting these errors

Comment: @Yuzui .. i already added **FormsModule** and **PaginationModule** .  Where to add **NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA** ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to import pagination module into your test bed configuration,
it will solve an issue

Answer (score 0):

if you have added pagination module into your test bed and in NgModule, just check if the component is part of the same NgModule as it seems as a different component
Please share your NgModule with the app tree structure

Please check your systemjs, you might have missed to mention the file for ng2-bootstrap